is there a safe way to use a Fan in a shower window?
I rent in a small apt in SoCal. The bathroom is tiny and built before bathroom fans became code. The only window is in the shower. The landlord said a true bathroom fan instillation would be too expensive and hard because the way the building was built.
Is there any fan that I can just put in the shower window that would be safe and move enough air to actually help? It is out of the way enough where it wouldn't really get splashed that much, but it's still in the shower and would definitely get a lot of mist. I would have to run an extension cord above the shower. I know,,,, so is there any solution here ? My main concern is stinking up a small apt, my second concern is steam and humidity (already have a dehumidifier in there.)
thanks for your help!!!!!

The landlord might not have a say in what it costs due to local regulations.  Electricity and water is never safe, why GFCI protection is required near water sources(showers/sinks).  A fan in a window should move enough air, if it is safe is the big question.  Since this is a rental, a licensed electrician should do the work.

Really an open window in a shower should equal a fan.  A fan is needed in a closed room.  It will be interesting with -20 wind blowing in the window.

Powerful AC-powered fans, about 6 inches in diameter, mounted in the window glass are common for bathroom and kitchen ventilation in many parts of Asia. I've never seen them in the US though.

@user71659 they were common in the UK at one point as well, but they're not compatible with double glazing (barring expensive custom windows) so fell out of favour. In an old building in California doble glazing may not be an issue

A fan with a long enough built in cord would allow you to run it more safely and easily. I'd just change the cord but I understand that's less of an option in some places

You might ask the landlord to consider a room-to-room ventilation fan. It would be installed in the wall between the bathroom and the hall outside the bathroom, with direction of flow INTO the bathroom. If you then open the window and turn on the fan while using the facilities, air will be forced from the hallway into the bathroom and straight out the window.
No need for extension cords, no danger of electrocution.

As a last resort, you might want to think about a 12 Volt fan that runs on "D" batteries or on a AC to DC adapter. See photo below from Home Depot, who I'm not affiliated with in any way. The fan could sit on the window sill and use batteries or you could route some low voltage wire from an adapter in the same room or the next room into the shower and connect to the fan. It's CFM is about 220 which is about what a bathroom fan would be.


I'd be tempted to run such a fan a a 12V lead acid battery (as used in burglar alarms and UPSs) and it the window faces south, use a small solar panel on the windowsill to top it up

Buy an automotive radiator fan - you could pick one up at the junkyard or pay more for a new one. Some of the savings will be offset by the need to clean the used one.
12V (so low hazard) and work just fine when driving through rain so fairly waterproof. Should be obvious that this is the electrically powered variant, not the one hanging off the crankshaft common on older vehicles.

Main problem with a radiator fan is finding the finger guards for it...

If you don't mind a bit of process you could remove the fan from the window while bathing and place it back again afterward. Alternatively, you could leave the fan in place and only unplug it from power while bathing.

The downside of that is that securing the cord becomes harder if it has to be easily removed.
